# Show that if the depth first search tree of G equals breadth first search tree of G then G is Tree

Tags: graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, proof

Please tell me if my proof is correct or not

> **We have a connected graph, and specific vertex u in V(G).
>
>   Suppose we compute the dfs tree of G rooted at u and obtain tree T.
>
>   Now imagine we compute the bfs tree of G rooted at u and we obtain the same tree T.
>
>   Prove that the only way this is possible is if G=T**

Proof by contradiction.

Assume that dfs tree and bfs tree are equal to T, but G is not equal to T.
This implies that G contains at least one edge not in T.
We also know that any such edges are part of a cycle, otherwise they would have been in T.
So there is at least one Cycle `C= p1, p2, p3, p_{k}` with `p_{k} = p1`, consisting of distinct nodes `k>= 3`, in G.
Assume that dfs and bfs algorithms will encounter the cycle at node `p1`.
Dfs will add the following edges to its tree `(p1, p2)`, ...., `(p_{k-2}`,`(p_{k-1})` whereas bfs begins by adding edges `(p1,p2)`, `(p1,p_{k})` to its tree.
Already we see that dfs tree is not equal to bfs tree since bfs contains `(p1,p_{k})` and dfs doesn’t contain this edge.
This contradicts our assumption that dfs and bfs have equal trees, and shows it must be the case that G=T.

Comment: Your proof implies that G is undirected (otherwise, `(p1,p_{k})` would not be added in BFS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theorem only holds for undirected graphs (take any strongly connected circle digraph as a counterexample).

Back to undirected graphs, for an intuitive approach note that dfs maximizes the tree height while bfs minimizes it. That means on the first circle `C` hit, the subtrees covering `C` will differ.

Your proof formalizes the idea, so in general  I'd say it's ok.

You didn't specify the dfs selection strategy, so there are 2 minor mistakes:

- Instead of `(p1,p2)`, then dfs may include `(p1,p_{k})` or none of the edges at all (  ). Of course, dfs will never include both edges while bfs always will.
- Dfs does not necessarily add `k-1` circle edges to `T`. However, it will have visited all circle vertices before retracting to `p1`, thus all circle vertices will have been added to `T` at this time. Thus `(p1,p_{k})` (dfs selection `(p1,p2)` on hitting `p1` for the first time) or `(p1,p2)` ( else ), resp., will not be added.

You could formalize the latter by proving a small lemma:

Let `(v, w)` be an edge that dfs is adding in step `n` ( wlog assuming that the dfs moved from `v` to `w` ), `T(n)` be the partial dfs tree at step (`n`). Then all nodes from the connected component `[w]` in the subgraph `G'` induced by `V(G) \ V(T(n))` will be added to the dfs tree before another edge `(w, x)` from `E(G)` will be added.